# Crystal 2013 export to pdf not working in web application

Tags: crystal-reports

Our company is using Crystal RAS 2013 OEM version, Everything seems to be working fine in our web application however when I try to export the report to pdf from the crystal tool bar I'm getting this error

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type
>   'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectModel.ISCRByteArray'.
>   This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM
>   component for the interface with IID
>   '{F3744886-4E8B-11D3-916E-00902741EE7C}' failed due to the following
>   error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002
>   (E_NOINTERFACE))

I have the RAS server running on a remote machine, I've created a setup app which is using the CRRuntime_13_0_11.msm modules which installed the correct .dlls in the GAC. The web app is running as 32bit.

Print button on the tool bar does not work as well. However when I set the PrintMode property on the CRYSTALREPORTVIEWER to ActiveX it prints the report.

Our product is a .net Web application

Comment: have a look at this: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3407221 Or
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8756ef09-9c94-4a01-9d2d-44e1275ad810/unable-to-publish-due-to-com-casting-error-0x80004002?forum=vbgeneral